# Remove Timezone info

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

How could I remove Timezone information from my time column without converting it into any other timezone when column datatype is **object**: 
`Sat Jun 10 2017 22:50:45 GMT+0300 (IDT)`

Request result: `2017-6-10 22:50:45`

Request dtype: `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: I'm assuming this is Pandas?

Comment: If it is a string, you can just remove the last n charcaters(15 here for the timezone part) by date[:-15]

Answer (score 6):

How about making a copy of the column (say, a Series called `time_series`) and removing the timezone using `time_series = time_series.apply(lambda d: d.replace(tzinfo=None))`?

Comment: Code: sf['time2'] = sf['time'].replace(tzinfo=None)
Result: TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

Comment: Maybe first you have to parse the column into `TimeSeries` type? You can use pandas.to_datetime.

Comment: `sf['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['time'])
sf['time3'] = sf['time2'].replace(tzinfo=None)`
Result: TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

event                  object
time                   object
time2          datetime64[ns]

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Comment: Now I see what the problem is. Instead of using `replace` on the whole series, use it on the elements (use a lambda function). I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeee!Thank you!
Could you explain me the reason or send me to read relevant topic!

Comment: But...I received time + 3 hours 
Sat Jun 10 2017 22:50:45 GMT+0300 (IDT) ----> 2017-06-11 01:50:45

Comment: As to the first comment: there are `replace` methods for both `Series` and `DateTime` objects, but they do different things. As to the second: I suppose you are in a different timezone? Then you have to apply a minus-three-hours `TimeDelta`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
tmpDatetime = tmpDatetime.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Comment: Code: sf['time2'] = sf['time'].replace(tzinfo=None)
Result: TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'

Comment: @Raya solve this problem by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095769/16733101