# Remove "plus" sing from date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How can I convert timestamp with timezone into normal "datetime" type?
When I print the `df.dtypes` of my df I get "object" as a type for this column not a "date time"

I have data frame:

```
| Resource | timestamp                       |
| -------- | --------------                  |
| 112      | 2011-10-01 00:38:44.546000+02:00|
| 113      | 2011-10-02 00:38:44.546000+02:00|
| 112      | 2011-10-03 00:38:44.546000+02:00|
| 115      | 2011-10-04 00:38:44.546000+02:00|
| 114      | 2011-10-05 00:38:44.546000+02:00|
```

I used

```
df_log['time:timestamp'] = df_log['time:timestamp'].apply(lambda x: dt.strftime(dt.fromisoformat(str(x)),'%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S'))
```

It has removed the '+' sign and gave me the date and time part, but I feel I am doing it wrong because i don't have good knowledge from datetime processing!
My goal is to just get date and time like "2011-10-01 00:38:44" and the type be "datetime" not object as I am still getting!

Comment: I don't get object. I get dtype of `datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]` after doing `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])`

Comment: How about `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(str).str[:19])`

Comment: @Ferris Thanks, your code is shorter and cleaner than mine although both gave the same results. My question was if I am doing it wrong knowing that it is datetime conversion process which I am trying to learn and understand :(

Comment: @DavidErickson my table were converted to pandas df from a log file (xes) - had it been originally df then you're right it would have produced datetime type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.replace('\+.*', ''))
df.info()

     #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   Resource   5 non-null      object        
 1   timestamp  5 non-null      datetime64[ns]

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.info()
```

---

Without the replace, you return a `datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]` date type:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.info()

     #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype                                
---  ------     --------------  -----                                
 0   Resource   5 non-null      object                               
 1   timestamp  5 non-null      datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]
```

You can also use:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.tz_convert(None)
```

from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59919896/6366770

Per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html?highlight=groupby%20sum), there was a change to how `pandas` handles `datetime` offsets in `0.24.0` released on January 25th, 2019:

---

```
*Previous behavior:
In [2]: pd.to_datetime("2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30")
Out[2]: Timestamp('2015-11-18 10:00:00')
In [3]: pd.Timestamp("2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30")
Out[3]: Timestamp('2015-11-18 15:30:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
# Different UTC offsets would automatically convert the datetimes to UTC (without a UTC timezone)
In [4]: pd.to_datetime(["2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30", "2015-11-18 16:30:00+06:30"])
Out[4]: DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-18 10:00:00', '2015-11-18 10:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
New behavior:
In [56]: pd.to_datetime("2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30")
Out[56]: Timestamp('2015-11-18 15:30:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')
In [57]: pd.Timestamp("2015-11-18 15:30:00+05:30")
Out[57]: Timestamp('2015-11-18 15:30:00+0530', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(330)')*
```

Comment: Thanks David for your reply. I am getting AttributeError when doing the replace code:
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].str.replace('\+.*', ''))

"AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: your code of dt.tz_convert(None) worked perfectly. I had to convert the column to datetime type first with UTC=True then I applied your tz conversion and I got the right time (which is -2 hours, i e 2011-10-01 00:38:44 gave me 2011-09-30 22:38:44)

Answer (score 1):

After the line of code you have. Try:

```
df_log['time:timestamp'] = datetime.strptime(df_log['time:timestamp'], '%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time, these lines solved my problem:

- Apply the timezone to the column and convert timestamp to date and time only:

  ```
  df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert(None)
  ```
- Remove the timezone without applying it to the column: (My favorite)

  ```
  df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).apply(lambda t: t.replace(tzinfo=None))
  ```

  **OR**

  ```
  df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).apply(lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
  ```

You should iterate through each row by using apply function with a lambda expression to use replace function because replace function work with `pandas.tslib.Timestampobject` not with `pandas.core.series.Series`. Otherwise, you will end up with this error: `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'`